# MySQL Error 1046: No database selected

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've created my first database for a lab, and when I try to run it in MySQL, I keep getting the same 1046 error: No database selected.

First, I run source (scriptfilename).sql and get:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> source McClureLab1.sql;
ERROR 1046 (3D000) at line 1 in file: 'McClureLab1.sql': No database selected
ERROR 1046 (3D000) at line 5 in file: 'McClureLab1.sql': No database selected
ERROR 1046 (3D000) at line 12 in file: 'McClureLab1.sql': No database selected
ERROR 1046 (3D000) at line 18 in file: 'McClureLab1.sql': No database selected
+-----------------------------+
| @lastID := LAST_INSERT_ID() |
+-----------------------------+
|                           0 |
+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

ERROR 1046 (3D000) at line 21 in file: 'McClureLab1.sql': No database selected
ERROR 1046 (3D000) at line 23 in file: 'McClureLab1.sql': No database selected
+-----------------------------+
| @lastID := LAST_INSERT_ID() |
+-----------------------------+
|                           0 |
+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

ERROR 1046 (3D000) at line 26 in file: 'McClureLab1.sql': No database selected
ERROR 1046 (3D000) at line 28 in file: 'McClureLab1.sql': No database selected
```

The same thing happens when I try to show my tables:

```
ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected
```

I'm not sure if there is something wrong with the database I've created, or if I'm entering commands incorrectly in MySQL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried to select your DB first?

```
USE yourDB;
```

If you need to create it:

CREATE DATABASE yourDB;

Comment: This worked! And such a simple solution. In our lab on location, we never needed to type USE database when inside MySQL, I had no idea that this was required. Should I add that line to my database code? Or is it simply a command needed before displaying my information in MySQL? Thanks for the help.

Comment: No need to add it to your database code as you specify the ```db_name``` when you make a connection. If not, then you should.